# Will Visual Studio work on Mac with ARM processor (Apple Silicon)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, arm, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

Will Visual Studio work flawlessly with the new Apple processor?

Because I read some blog that, they said some barrier in with third party software with new ARM processor on Mac.

like this,

https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-we-want-to-bring-vs-code-to-apples-mac-on-arm-silicon/
https://www.newsbreak.com/news/1601370814181/microsoft-we-want-to-bring-vs-code-to-apples-mac-on-arm-silicon

Comment: The linked article talks about "Visual Studio Code" (and not about "Visual Studio"). Both exist for the Mac. Are you really interested in "Visual Studio"?

Comment: yes, i need information regarding how VS perform in ARM based processor. because various purpose i use this. (language like react,dart etc.)

Comment: Your answer is contradicting in itself. React, Dart etc. are mainly supported by "Visual Studio **Code**", not by "Visual Studio". Note the two different names. It sounds to me as if you are saying "VS" but really mean "VSC". And yes, Microsoft created the confusion in the first place.

Comment: (language like react,dart etc.) it just example for current situation for my use.but i use this also for other technologies.

Comment: Sorry, I'm giving up. I don't understand which of the two products you are really interested in.

Comment: yes i am asking for both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio.i got it what you ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio works just fine using Rosetta 2. MS are working on a ARM build.

VS Code should be available in the next few weeks. You can download an experimental ARM64 build just now

Comment: can you provide some detail or link.

Comment: What about Xamarin and Mono?

Comment: In terms of VS. I have tried this myself. I have access to the Apple DTK. For VS code see https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/#osx

Comment: For Xamarin, https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10005

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code? No.
Visual Studio for Mac? Yes.

Microsoft has acknowledged the problem (see their tweet), but as of today, Visual Studio Code does not work at all. It crashes at launch.

[image]